# jquery plugin inheritance

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have created a jquery plugin to perform a watermark style on a textbox.

Now i want to create another plugin that inherits from this plugin - is this possible? both plugins perform very similar tasks and dont want to rewrite the similar functions.